# Cannot format date time in chart.js - vanilla js

Tags: javascript

I trying to display date in this format: "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm", But when I trying like this:

```
     const formatDate = "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm";

  mikeFWLabelChart = moment(mikeFWLabelChart).format(formatDate);

 const a = new Chart(canvasElement, {
    data: {
      labels: mikeFWLabelChart,
      datasets: [{
        type: 'line',
        label: 'Метра',
        data: mikeFWDataChart,
        borderWidth: 1
      }]
    },
    options: {
      scales: {
        xAxes: [{
          type:       "time",
          time:       {
              format: formatDate,
              tooltipFormat: 'll'
          },
          scaleLabel: {
              display:     true,
              labelString: 'Date'
          }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
          scaleLabel: {
              display:     true,
              labelString: 'value'
          }
      }]
      }
    }
  })
};
```

I receive error on X axis INVALID DATE..

Also I trying to change format date without moment code:

```
mikeFWLabelChart = moment(mikeFWLabelChart).format(formatDate);
```

with `options code -> format` But they still look like this format: `2023-02-16T05:00:00.000Z`

How to change date format in this YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm ?

Comment: Maybe try .toLocaleString() method? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString

Comment: I trying like this: 
const formatDate = "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm";
  mikeFWLabelChart = moment(mikeFWLabelChart).format(formatDate).toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: 'Europe/Sofia' });

But still receive INVALID DATE

Comment: I was thinking of toLocaleString() instead of moment.js. I don't know the details of `mikeFWLabelChart`, but i added examples with and without moment.js.

Comment: BTW, sorry I meant .toISOString()

Answer (score 0):

With moment.js you do it like this:

```js
const formatDate = "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm";
const date = new Date("2023-02-16T05:00:00.000Z");
const formattedDate = moment.utc(date).format(formatDate);
console.log(formattedDate)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js"></script>
```

With .toISOString() you do it like this:

```js
const date = new Date("2023-02-16T05:00:00.000Z").toISOString();
const formattedDate = date.slice(0, 16).replace("T", " ");
console.log(formattedDate);
```

Comment: What to put in the string of New Date ("").toISOString(); 
I have date who come from the API mikeFWLabelChart ?

Comment: Edit your question and add a sample response from the API then.

Comment: It's a simple my dates come from  labels: mikeFWLabelChart, with this format: 2023-02-16T05:00:00.000Z I want to change the format YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm I think my question was asked correctly

Comment: No, it's not clear. Sorry, cannot read minds. I don't know how you API response looks like.If its an array, you can use for example Array.map() method to map the dates to desired format.